# Objective C adding items to nsmutablearray returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add items from an NSArray to an NSMutableArray like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [tableData count]; i++){
        [purchaseOrder.objects addObject:[tableData objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog(@"%@",[tableData objectAtIndex:i]);
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", purchaseOrder.objects);
```

but `purchaseOrder.objects` returns nil: here is what `NSLog(@"%@",[tableData objectAtIndex:i]);` is returning:

```
2015-04-30 08:57:36.510 MyApp[7055:1475885] {
    POIndex = "094 Spray Foam";
    PONumber = "ABC123/028";
}
2015-04-30 08:57:36.511 MyApp[7055:1475885] {
    POIndex = "095 Drywall";
    PONumber = "ABC124/029";
}
2015-04-30 08:57:36.511 MyApp[7055:1475885] {
    POIndex = "100 Stairs";
    PONumber = "ABC125/032";
}
```

I am looking for away to have the PONumber as the key and POIndex as the value. Here is how my arrays are defined:

MasterController:

```
@property NSMutableArray *objects;
```

Detailer Controller:

```
 NSArray *tableData = [dataSource.areaData GetPurchaseOrderItems:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",areaPickerSelectionString,unitPickerSelectionString]];
```

Comment: I expect `purchaseOrder.objects` has not been allocated.  Also look at `[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]`.

Comment: if (!purschaseOrder.objects) purchaseOrder.objects = [NSMutableArray array];

Comment: @trojanfoe how to allocate `purchaseOrder.objects` ?

Comment: purchaseOrder.objects = [NSMutableArray new];

Comment: The `PurchaseOrder` object should do it in its `init` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must initialize your MutableArray before use .

write below code before you for loop.

```
if(!purchaseOrder.objects){// If Array not initialize 
    purchaseOrder.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

Hope This helps you.

Comment: Shouldn't the `PurchaseObject` be doing it instead?

Comment: that works, but now my purchaseOrder is being populated like to: `POIndex,
    PONumber,
    POIndex,
    PONumber,
    POIndex,
    PONumber` how do I get the PONumber as the key and POIndex as the value ?

Comment: can you add some logs in your question for that.

Comment: @user979331 That's a different question so create a new question.  Also if that has solved your problem, don't you think an upvote is in order?

Comment: I will help you but if my answer solve your posted issue please mark this as  answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to allocate the PurchaseObjects as below

```
purchaseOrder.objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

And then use below code

```
NSMutableDictionary *subDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in tableData) {
    [subDict setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"POIndex"] forKey:[dict objectForKey:@"PONumber"]];
    [purchaseOrder.objects addObject:subDict];
}
NSLog(@"@@@@@@@purchaseOrder.objects Array is:%@",purchaseOrder.objects);
```

It will result in the array with dictionaries with required content..

Hope it helps you..